# How to print a special unicode character in a zsh script

Tags: shell, zsh

I am trying to print a special unicode character when two files are not different.
My code below produces an error saying that "-e: command not found"

```
    if [ -n "`diff file1 file2`" ]
            then `echo -e "\u2713"`
    fi
```

Edit: I am using ZSH

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of the backticks around the echo.

```
if [ -n "`diff file1 file2`" ]
        then echo -e "\u2713"
fi
```

Also, if you just want to know if the two files are the same, checking the exit code from `diff` or `cmp` is more efficient than seeing if they have any output. I recommend `cmp` since as it simply detects differences without calculating patches.

```
if ! cmp -s file1 file2; then
    echo -e "\u2713"
fi
```

Comment: This produces the output "-e \u2713". What I want is for that special character (a checkmark) to be printed

Comment: What is your shell? Are you sure it's bash? All of these work for me: `echo -e "\u2713"` / `echo -e '\u2713'` / `echo $'\u2713'`. It's weird that `-e` would be printed, that indicates that you're using some antiquated shell or echo command that doesn't support `-e`. To be fair, `echo -e` isn't fully portable, but it is if you're using bash.

Comment: @24hp: If you get this error message, I guess you wrote it as `echo "-e \u2713"` and not the way John Kugelman was suggesting.

Comment: Does anyone else have issues if the `u` character is not capitalized?